Getting #VALUE error in VBA function when calling the function with the proper data types
I have a simple (currently useless) VBA function:
Function similarNames(allnames As Range, thisname As String) As String
    For Each cell In allnames.Cells
        Set curName = cell.Value
        similarNames = curName
        Next
End Function

I call it in my spreadsheet with similarNames(I3:I7,"irrelevantstring") and I get a #VALUE error and excel says "a value used in the formula is the wrong data type." It doesn't indicate which, but my first argument is a range and the second argument is a string. I'm not sure what's causing the error.
I've tried getting rid of the for loop and hard coding an output for the function, and i get the expected result. But as soon as I bring the for loop back in the error persists.

SET is for object assignment. Might need this to be just curName = cell.Value If you wanted a reference to the cell itself, then you use Set, as in Set curName = cell This is such a strange function though - its confusing on every level.

What should the function return? You're never using thisname. Please clarify.

You don't "set" a string variable, so try:
Function similarNames(allnames As Range, thisname As String) As String

    Dim curName As String

    For Each cell In allnames.Cells
        curName = cell.Value
        similarNames = curName
    Next

End Function

though this will only return the last value found. This is probably not what you are after.
